# Debugging the following perl script on hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I am working on a perl script that does search for a name in hash returns the phone number of that person. Just Like looking for a key in hash and returning the value of that found key. Otherwise It would print "name not found in book". I am unable to access the elements when I am giving a value that is existing in the Hash. What do I need to modify the code?

```
$namesearch="";
%phoneNumbers={"ramu"=>123,"rishi"=>456,"sai"=>789};
while($namesearch ne "END")
{
   print("Enter name to search:\n");
   $namesearch=<STDIN>;
   chomp $namesearch;
if(exists($phoneNumbers{$namesearch}))
{
     print "The phone Number of $namesearch is: ($phoneNumbers{$namesearch})\n";
 }
 elsif($namesearch eq "END")
 {
     last;
 }
 else
 {
     print "Name not found in book\n";
  }   
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
output 
Enter name to search:
ramu
Name not found in book
```

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings 'all';`. Turning on warnings would have given you a clue: "Reference found where even-sized list expected" (pointing to the line `%phoneNumbers={...};`)

Comment: Now it's showing some compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good practice you should use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) pragma in your code to make it easy to debug.

**Strict**

> The strict pragma disables certain Perl expressions that could
>   behave unexpectedly or are difficult to debug, turning them into
>   errors. The effect of this pragma is limited to the current file or
>   scope block.

**Warnings**

> This pragma works just like the strict pragma. This means that the
>   scope of the warning pragma is limited to the enclosing block. It also
>   means that the pragma setting will not leak across files (via use,
>   require or do). This allows authors to independently define the degree
>   of warning checks that will be applied to their module.

I did some changes in your code and there are a few things that you should do to make it works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#Always declare your variables
my $namesearch = "";

#Change your hash ref to a simple hash
my %phoneNumbers = ( "ramu" => 123, "rishi" => 456, "sai" => 789 );

while ( $namesearch ne "END" ) {
    print("Enter name to search:\n");
    $namesearch = <STDIN>;
    chomp $namesearch;
    if ( exists( $phoneNumbers{$namesearch} ) ) {
        print
          "The phone Number of $namesearch is: ($phoneNumbers{$namesearch})\n";
    }
    elsif ( $namesearch eq "END" ) {
        last;
    }
    else {
        print "Name not found in book\n";
    }
}
```

Also check at perldoc about references ( [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) ) There are some explanations about how to use properly, because the syntax will change depending on what variable are you using like arrays or hashes for example.

Comment: Instead of having the global `$namesearch`, I'd recommend localizing it: `while(1){my $namesearch = <STDIN>;...; last if $namesearch eq 'END';...}`